# How can I use Bootstrap button addons in my MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having difficulty getting Bootstrap's [button addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) to work in my MVC view. I'm using the latest NuGet version of ASP.NET MVC (5.1 rc1) and Bootstrap (3.03).

I have the following in my view (now that I've pared it back to just hand-coded HTML rather than using `Html.EditorFor()`, in an attempt to getting it to work):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
<form action="xxx" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="T3k..." />
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The problem is that, when this is displayed in the browser (Chrome 32 / IE 11), there's a big gap between the input box and the button. Like this: [image]

If I reduce the size of the `div` surrounding the `input-group` `div` to `col-lg-3` or smaller, it's fine. But anything larger than that leaves a gap.

It's as though there's a maximum size on the `input` - and indeed, all my `inputs` do seem to be smaller their container `div`...

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default `Site.css` stylesheet that comes with a new MVC 5 project has a rule that limits the max-width of inputs. What you're getting is the result of the control spanning the full available width like it's supposed to, but then the input, itself, is being constrained to a defined width. Just comment out that piece of the stylesheet and everything will work as it should.

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

It's a pretty egregious shortcut the team seems to have taken in order to quickly build the sample site.

Comment: Is there any alternative beside comment out that piece of CSS? I want my controls have max-width 280px, but without a gap between them?

Comment: No. Form controls in BS3 are grid-based and responsive. If you use any static width, they won't work.

Comment: Willy, I'm not saying this is a good thing in the long run, but adding the css: 'input,select,textarea { max-width: 100%;}' within the scope of what you're trying to group will allow you to do what you want and keep your Site.css as is.

Comment: From a mobile (small-screen) perspective, any defined width other than 100% (and using the BS3 grid to control sizing) will end up with sub-optimal layout. If your layout is so exacting that the BS3 grid can't accommodate it, you should probably be re-evaluating the layout instead.