# Bootstrap input-group textbox+input-group-addon not aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to have a simple Bootstrap problem. When using `input-group` + `input-group-addon` (or `input-group-button`) thet textbox appears on the left side of the screen while the addon or button is on the right side of the screen, when screen is maximized.

I've replaced the index.cshtml of a standard mvc5/visual studio 2013 project with this code to re-produce this effect. What am I missing?

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@@</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197090/how-can-i-use-bootstrap-button-addons-in-my-mvc-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you add the text-center class to each element it will center them.